# Docker composer and volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have generated a docker yml file with necessary images. I have placed index.php in the current directory which is required by nginx to display the page and when i run docker-compose up command, no files from my working directory detected in  /application directory from container.

```
version: "2"
services:

    memcached:
      image: memcached:alpine
      container_name: juzpay-docker-memcached

    mysql:
      image: mysql:8.0
      container_name: juzpay-docker-mysql
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - .:/application
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=juzpay_db
        - MYSQL_USER=root
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root123
      ports:
        - "8082:3306"

    webserver:
      image: nginx:alpine
      container_name: juzpay-docker-webserver
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
          - ./dockerapp:/application
          - ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      ports:
       - "8080:80"

    php-fpm:
      build: phpdocker/php-fpm
      container_name: juzpay-docker-php-fpm
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - ./dockerapp:/application
        - ./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
```

Comment: You can create a persistent volume and use this for you&#39;re Docker-Stack.

Comment: According to this line `- ./dockerapp:/application` you are not mounting your current directory (I'm assuming root of the project) into your container.